# subtracting Dates and saving value in different column of database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Ok, so What i want to do is take Two dates, subtract them and insert their answer (in integers) to another column. Should be like 15 days and so on. The dates to be fetched are stored in the database. The answer needs to be in DAYS
this is my gridview code:

```
<div class="gview"> 
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="gview" DataKeyNames="PID" Width="613px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PID" HeaderText="PID" SortExpression="PID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Pname" HeaderText="Pname" SortExpression="Pname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ward" HeaderText="Ward" SortExpression="Ward" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Bed" HeaderText="Bed" SortExpression="Bed" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AdmitDate" HeaderText="AdmitDate" SortExpression="AdmitDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DischargeDate" HeaderText="DischargeDate" SortExpression="DischargeDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NumOfDays" HeaderText="NumOfDays" SortExpression="NumOfDays" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></FooterStyle>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PID], [Pname], [Gender], [Department], [Ward], [Bed], [Status], [AdmitDate], [DischargeDate], [NumOfDays] FROM [Patient]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
 </div>
```

This is my C# code:

```
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string str = "update Patient (Department, Ward, Bed, Status, AdmitDate, DischargeDate) set Department= @Department,Ward=@Ward,Bed=@Bed,Status=@Status,AdmitDate=@AdmitDate,DischargeDate=@DischargeDate   where PID = '" + TextBox3.Text + "'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ward", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bed", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmitDate", TextBox1.Text);
    DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DischargeDate", TextBox2.Text);
    DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text.ToString());
    var diff = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text.ToString()));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDays", diff);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    show();
    Response.Write("Record Updated");
}
```

Now when I click the button it generates the following error:

> SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '10.00:00:00' is out of range.  Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.

I did quite a research and found out the idea that i have implemented. But it's no good so far. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The HTML is pretty much irrelevant here, as is most of the SQL. What *would* be useful would be the sample values - we don't know what the textbox values are, which is clearly crucial to the problem. (If you're trying to store 10 days in a TIME column, that's just not going to work...)

Comment: The type of both columns that store Dates is set to DateTime and these are the values that i am inserting. http://prntscr.com/666tl8 (using a Calender)

Comment: Well you're passing a TimeSpan as your NumOfDays parameter - so what's the type of *that* column? That's being inferred as SqlDbType.Time, by the looks of it.

Comment: DataType of NumOfDays is _int_

Comment: Then why are you trying to set the value as a `TimeSpan`? How do you expect anything to know that you're trying to extract a number of days from that?

Comment: Sir, i am totally new to this. I researched and that's what i found out. So there is no point in asking me questions. If you can explain, awesome. If not, thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm trying to help you to help yourself in future. It's vital that you understand your own code. In this line of code: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDays", diff);` you're setting your `NumOfDays` parameter value to be a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Just wondering, if dates are in SQL, why can't you use SQL duilt-in function DATEDIFF(DAY, firstdate, secondDate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the researching and help from the people above, this is what worked for me:

```
DateTime AdmitDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmitDate", AdmitDate.ToShortDateString());
        DateTime DischargeDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DischargeDate", DischargeDate.ToShortDateString());
        var diff = (DischargeDate - AdmitDate).Days;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDays", diff);
```

I had to use `ToShortDateString` because i didn't want to add the `Time` bit to my `AdmitDate` and `DischargeDate`. Since i am using `DateTime` datatype for those columns, it was automatically adding the `null` time that is `12:00AM`. `ToShortDateString` helped me get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

These lines:

```
 var diff = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text.ToString()));
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDays", diff);
```

set the value of the `@NumOfDays` parameter to a `TimeSpan`. Firstly, I'd recommend explicitly setting the data type you *expect* to use - it'll make it easier to find the error earlier.

Next, you say you want the value of the column to be a number of days, but you haven't said anywhere how you want the `TimeSpan` to be converted. You probably want to use `TimeSpan.Days` for this, which assumes you don't care about any sub-day information. So:

```
var diff = ...; // Code as before, but see notes. 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumOfDays", SqlDbType.Int).Value = diff.Days;
```

However, for computing `diff`:

- Ideally, separate out your presentation layer from your storage layer. It's odd to deal with both controls and SQL in the same class, IMO.
- I would suggest parsing with the expected format and culture. Ideally, use a date picker control on the client-side to avoid users having to type in dates at all; you can then ensure it will use a standard format (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd)
- I would encourage you to rename your controls to indicate intent, rather than just a type name followed by a number.
- If your users *are* typing in text, use `TryParse` or `TryParseExact` to cleanly handle user error.
- You don't need to call `ToString` on the `Text` property of a `TextBox` - it's already a string
- I would use the `-` operator for simplicity
- I'd use separate local variables to make it easier to diagnose issues.

So if you *do* want to use a textbox, it would be something like:

```
DateTime start, end;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(startTextBox.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                            out start))
{
    // Invalid start - handle appropriately.
}
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(endTextBox.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                            out end))
{
    // Invalid end - handle appropriately.
}
var diff = end - start;
```

Next, look at your SQL:

```
string str = "update Patient (Department, Ward, Bed, Status, AdmitDate, DischargeDate) set Department= @Department,Ward=@Ward,Bed=@Bed,Status=@Status,AdmitDate=@AdmitDate,DischargeDate=@DischargeDate   where PID = '" + TextBox3.Text + "'";
```

This has two important problems:

- You're including the `PID` directly in the SQL. **Don't do that.** It's a serious potential security flaw ([SQL Injection Attack](http://bobbytables.com)). You're using parameters for everything else - why no the PID?
- You're not using the `NumOfDays` parameter or mentioning the `NumOfDays` column, so obviously that's not going to be affected.

Comment: Ok. the code worked but the trouble i am having now is that Time is also being saved in the columns when all i want are dates. and NumOfDays column is still empty. prntscr.com/667mfj I only want Dates in those coulmns. Plus no difference of dates in the required column

Comment: @SanaQureshi: Well it sounds like your columns are an inappropriate type then - and I've just looked, and your SQL doesn't *use* the `NumOfDays` parameter. It's really important that you learn to diagnose this sort of thing yourself though. (I've edited my answer accordingly.)

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
DateTime admitdate = new DateTime(2015, 2, 17);
DateTime dischargedate = new DateTime(2015, 2, 19);
var diff = dischargedate.Subtract(admitdate).TotalDays; 
// it will give you total days in this case it will give you 2 days
```

instead of this

```
var diff = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text.ToString()));
```

**Edit:**

```
    DateTime admitdate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    DateTime dischargedate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    var diff = dischargedate.Subtract(admitdate).TotalDays;
```

Comment: i want to get dates from the calender, not hard coded

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Enter ID' to data type int.   this is what i am getting now

Comment: It is because TotalDays return double while your data type is int .you should type cast double to int

Comment: Ok. the code worked but the trouble i am having now is that Time is also being saved in the columns when all i want are dates. and NumOfDays column is still empty. http://prntscr.com/667mfj     I only want Dates in those coulmns. Plus no difference of dates in the required column

Comment: @SanaQureshi you did not include NumOfDays in you query..if you don't want time with date you should use data data type instead of datatime data type in sql